# How to hide column in multicolumn listbox using VBA

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, listbox

I am using a 2-dimensional array to load data into a multi-column List Box.

I would like to hide a specific column, but don't know how. I can't just exclude the data — because I want to reference it later as a hidden column — but I don't want the user to see it.

Here is what I have so far:

```
For x = 0 To UBound(ReturnArray, 2)
NISSLIST.ListBox1.Clear 'Make sure the Listbox is empty
NISSLIST.ListBox1.ColumnCount = UBound(ReturnArray, 1) 'Set the number of columns
'Fill the Listbox
NISSLIST.ListBox1.AddItem x 'Additem creates a new row
For y = 0 To UBound(ReturnArray, 1)
    NISSLIST.ListBox1.LIST(x, y) = ReturnArray(y, x) 'List(x,y) X is the row number, Y the column number
    If y = 3 Then 'Want to hide this column in listbox
         NISSLIST.ListBox1.NOIDEA '<<< HELP HERE <<<, What do I put to hide this column of my multi-column listbox????
    End If
   Next y
 Next x
```

Answer (score 4):

The ColumnHidden property only applies to RowSource queries and will not include that column in the listbox values.
If you want the values to still be in the listbox and be hidden, the only way to do so in VBA is through the ColumnWidths property.

To hide the 4th column (index 3) you would put the following code:

```
NISSLIST.ListBox1.ColumnWidths = (";;;0cm")
```

Or if you want it in a loop like the one in the question:

```
Dim strWidths As String
For y = 0 To UBound(ReturnArray, 1)
    If y = 3 Then
        strWidths = strWidths + "0cm;"
    Else
        strWidths = strWidths + ";"
    End If
Next y
NISSLIST.ListBox1.ColumnWidths = (strWidths)
```

Though I would not suggest doing this in a nested loop as it only needs to be done once.

The widths of the other columns will be equally divided unless you specify a width.

I know this is likely no longer useful to the original poster but it may help others (like me) who still run into this issue. It is quite useful for hiding the Key column for when you want users to be able to manipulate data in the listbox.

Comment: This is the solution. For internationalisation, I joined the width-values in the column-width-definition-string using  `Application.International(xlListSeparator)`. I had some bad expiriences with cell-validations and `;`

Answer (score 0):

Via [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194134.aspx)
`NISSLIST.ListBox1.Column(x,3).ColumnHidden=-1`

Comment: returns Run-Time error 381 "could not get the Column property. Invalid Property array index.

Comment: Hmm try 2 instead for column? edit: hmm but you did start at 0... not sure XD Edit2: oh, y is row, not index. See edit above.

Comment: Same error, I have 9 columns here so That's not it. :(

Comment: (x, 3) returns same error 381. So confusing. It really seems like this should work.

Comment: [`If the user has made no selection when you refer to a column in a combo box or list box, the Column property setting will be Null`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff834793.aspx) uhh so apparently property only works if something is selected XD

Comment: You're a master at finding obscure Microsoft nonsense!!, seriously though, I have to select something? ugh! Ok, so I select my first row like this NISSLIST.ListBox1.Selected(0) = True,   and then I still get an error for the columnHidden line.. new error now. Run-Time error 424 Object required. WTF? LOL    FYI: I am using this NISSLIST.ListBox1.Column(3).ColumnHidden = -1 otherwise I get the old 381 error about array index blah blah

Comment: Uh it's just google. I am not going to read how to select something but the error is suggesting that `nisslist` is bad.

Comment: I don't know then, because NISSLIST is not bad. If I comment out the line about hiding a column then it populates the listbox just fine. (with my first row selected, my select is correct)  :(    Maybe I will look into the possibility of setting col width to 0. It's crazy that it's so difficult to have a hidden column in a listbox. forms should be able to handle hidden data easily as it's a regular need.

Comment: Yea, I am not sure what's going on :/